# Custom Font Not Working on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I have read lots of articles on getting a custom font to work on a rails app, yet I am still having trouble with it.

I downloaded X font from dafont.com.  I unzipped it, and the package contained x.otf.  I then installed it on my computer, but when I use it in my app the font is distorted.

I then downloaded Y font from dafont.com.  I unzipped, it contained y.ttf.  I did not install it on my machine and instead placed it in /assets/fonts.  I then added the following in my custom.css.scss file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nokia Pure Headline';    
  src: url('/assets/fonts/y.ttf');
  src: url('/assets/fonts/y.ttf?iefix') format('eot'),
  url('/assets/fonts/y.woff') format('woff'),
  url('/assets/fonts/y.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('/assets/fonts/y.svg#webfont3AwWkQXK') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I then called it in my custom.css.scss stylesheet

```
body {
    font-family: y;
}
```

When I refresh still no success.  Any clues as to why X is distorted, or Y will not work?

Comment: try placing them in the public directory - /public/assets/fonts/ - I know this is out of rails asset pipeline but you will get it working

Comment: That worked for Y.  I uninstalled X, and tried the same thing, but now X will not work.  I do not know anything about font types, but I wonder if the format has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use asset pipelines with fonts.
First add in application.rb :

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Rename `custom.css.scss` file into `custom.css.scss.erb` and use `asset_path` for each font file like this :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nokia Pure Headline';    
  src: url('<%= asset_path("y.ttf") %>');
  src: url('<%= asset_path("y.ttf?iefix") %>') format('eot'),
  url('<%= asset_path("y.woff") %>') format('woff'),
  url('<%= asset_path("y.ttf") %>') format('truetype'),
  url('<%= asset_path("y.svg#webfont3AwWkQXK") %>') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```